# Log transforming + a constant for negative data- ANOVA

Tags: anova, data-transformation, residuals, normality-assumption

I have data (change in mass) ranging from ~ -400 to + 4,000. I'd like to run an ANOVA comparing change in mass in different treatments. When I plot the residuals they are not normal and the residual variances are not equal. To normalize the residuals and deal with the variance I transformed the data via a log transform and added a constant as so: log(change in mass + 401).

Is it ok to add such a large number to normalize the data? Is there an alternative test or transformation that would better deal with the lack of normality?